# Content height:auto not working

Tags: html, css

I think that I might have coded wrongly (or did it the short way), and I am trying to figure out how I am able to make the .content holds all the elements have an auto height which is dependent to what's in it. However, when I used height:auto; to the content, the content disappears totally (either it's height is gone or the .content did not accurately contains the elements in them.

Here, it affects the footer as well.

```
.content {
   width:930px;
   background: #eeeeee;
   background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #eeeeee 0%, #f4f4f4 100%);
   background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#eeeeee), color-stop(100%,#f4f4f4));
   background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #eeeeee 0%,#f4f4f4 100%);
   background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #eeeeee 0%,#f4f4f4 100%);
   background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #eeeeee 0%,#f4f4f4 100%);
   background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #eeeeee 0%,#f4f4f4 100%);
   filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#eeeeee', endColorstr='#f4f4f4',GradientType=0 );
   border: 2px solid rgb(34, 178, 76);
   border: 2px solid rgba(34, 178, 76, .5);
   -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
   background-clip: padding-box;
   height: 800px;
   margin: 93px auto;
   margin-bottom: 10px !important;
}
```

**Website LIVE: http://nbtfootball.com.sg/wwfc**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `height: 800px` and add `overflow: auto`.

The problem is caused by the floating elements inside it.

```
.content {
  width:930px;
  background: #eeeeee;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #eeeeee 0%, #f4f4f4 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#eeeeee), color-stop(100%,#f4f4f4));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #eeeeee 0%,#f4f4f4 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #eeeeee 0%,#f4f4f4 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #eeeeee 0%,#f4f4f4 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #eeeeee 0%,#f4f4f4 100%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#eeeeee', endColorstr='#f4f4f4',GradientType=0 );
  border: 2px solid rgb(34, 178, 76);
  border: 2px solid rgba(34, 178, 76, .5);
  -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  /* height: 800px; REMOVE */
  margin: 93px auto;
  margin-bottom: 10px !important;
  overflow: auto; /* ADD */
```

}

Comment: Yes indeed, very true.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to add `height: auto` because it's the default value.

The reason is because you're not clear the float of elements with `float: right` or `float: left` style. Try to use `clear: both` on floating elements or better using [clearfix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8554043/what-is-clearfix)